# How to create default taxonomy term for a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

When i install a custom post type as plugin,it will create 3 default category automatically like apple,sony,nokia.
How is it possible ?
My custom post & taxonomy code:

```
function brands() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Brands', 'brands_creator' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Brand', 'brands_creator' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New Brand', 'brands_creator' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New Brand', 'brands_creator' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Brand', 'brands_creator' ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'New Brand', 'brands_creator' ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'View Brand', 'brands_creator' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search Brands', 'brands_creator' ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'No Brands found', 'brands_creator' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No Brands found in Trash', 'brands_creator' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Brand:', 'brands_creator' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Brands', 'brands_creator' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'description' => 'Brands filterable by genre',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor','thumbnail','revisions'),
        'taxonomy' => 'brand_type',
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' =>get_bloginfo('url').'/wp-content/plugins/brands-creator/images/brand.png',
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( 'brands_creator', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'brands' );

function brand_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
      'brand_type',
        'brands_creator',
        array(
        'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Brands Type'
                ),

        )
    );

}
add_action( 'init', 'brand_taxonomy');

# Default Category that will create automatically#
function default_brand_type() {
    wp_insert_term(
        'Example Category',
        'brand_taxonomy',
        array(
          'description' => 'MFG Product taxonomy.',
          'slug'        => 'dmfg'
        )
    );
    wp_insert_term(
        'EMFG',
        'brand_type',
        array(
          'description' => 'EMFG Product taxonomy.',
          'slug'        => 'demfg'
        )
    );
    wp_insert_term(
        'OMFG',
        'brand_type',
        array(
          'description' => 'OMFG Product taxonomy.',
          'slug'        => 'domfg'
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'default_brand_type' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got error in Your Code

you insert taxonomy before register taxonomy

after_setup_theme Load Before init So not insert taxonomy Please change after_setup_theme  To init 
[More Detail](http://theme.fm/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/wordpress-internals-how-wordpress-boots-up-382x600.png)

Comment: Thanks @Bhavik Patel for answer.                               But How can i solve it?

Comment: Please Change Your Function in  after_setup_theme to init Ex :                                     add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'default_brand_type');  TO  add_action('init', 'default_brand_type' );